# Unmet Dependencies Issue: Missing Packages for QEMU and Docker Installation

Tags: 20.04, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, docker

I am currently facing an issue with installing certain packages on my Ubuntu system. I am attempting to install QEMU for virtualization and Docker for containerization. However, I am encountering unmet dependencies when I try to install these packages.

The specific error messages I'm getting include:

```
E: Package 'qemu-system-x86' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libaio1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libfdt1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libibverbs1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libpmem1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'librdmacm1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'liburing2' has no installation candidate
```

I have tried updating my package sources using `sudo apt update` and checking the repositories, but the required packages seem to be missing. I've also searched for alternative package names and versions, but with no luck.

My system information:

- Ubuntu version: 22.04
- Architecture: amd64

[sudo apt update image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GSPn.png)

[apt policy qemu-system-x86](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mfn9.png)

Is anyone else experiencing similar issues? Could this be related to repository changes, compatibility, or something else? Any guidance on how to address this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1484118/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `apt policy qemu-system-x86`

Comment: It seems your repositories is a mix of Debian, Focal and Jammy sources. This will inherently lead to some version conflicts down the road.

Comment: I was having issues installing the postgresql desktop app and now having similar issues in docker desktop, even though docker is installed the desktop application creates this issue. does this have any solution ? @ArturMeinild